# Send API after payment completed WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, api, woocommerce

I have an e-commerce on Wordpress where I put my products for sale through WooCommerce and a demand arose for an advantage club where, after payment was made, it would send data to an API to create an account on a platform and when is no longer paid to be deactivated by the same API. How can I do this? Is there any way?

I looked for documentation on the internet but I couldn't find much.

Comment: "couldn't find much", well to me [the list of WooCommerce hooks](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/hooks/hooks.html) looks like quite a lot for a start. What have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use, a hook that runs when an ordered is marked as completed:

```
woocommerce_order_status_completed
```

if that doesnt work for you, you need to check the payment gateway provider, to see what hooks they offer